# GSM - AT+STGI=21 how to confirm it using STK AT Command

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-toolkit

hi am working on GSM STK to recharge airtel sim.am stuck at last point.how to confirm it using AT Command,
am using below code

```
AT+STGI=25
+STGI:25,0,0,24,"00410069007200740065006C0020004C0069007600650021",7
+STGI:25,1,22,"00450061007300790020004300680061007200670065"
+STGI:25,2,16,"00450061007300790020005600410053"
+STGI:25,3,26,"0045006100730079002000420069006C006C0020005000610079"
+STGI:25,4,20,"005700680061007400730020006E00650077003F"
+STGI:25,5,32,"004C0061006E0064006C0069006E0065002000420069006C006C007000610079"
+STGI:25,6,20,"00410069007200740065006C0020004400540048"
+STGI:25,7,24,"00410069007200740065006C0020004D006F006E00650079"

OK
at+stgr=25,1
OK

+STIN: 24
AT+STGI=24
+STGI:24,0,0,0,22,"00450061007300790020004300680061007200670065",4
+STGI:24,1,16,"00520065006300680061007200670065"
+STGI:24,2,26,"0047004900460054002000520065006300680061007200670065"
+STGI:24,3,30,"00430075007200720065006E0074002000420061006C0061006E00630065"
+STGI:24,4,22,"004300680061006E006700650020004D00500049004E"

OK
AT+STGR=24,1
OK

+STIN: 23
AT+STGR=23,"9840xxxxxx" // Phone Number
OK

+STIN: 23
AT+STGR=23,"10"   //Amount
OK

+STIN: 23
AT+STGR=23,"xxxx"   // PIN
OK

+STIN: 21
AT+STGI=21
+STGI:21,1,1,118,"0050 006C 0073 0020 0063 006F 006E 0066 0069 0072 006D 0020 0052 0065 0063 0068 0061 0072 0067 0065 0020 006F 0066 0020 0052 0073 002E 0020 0031 0030 0020 0074 006F 0020 004D 006F 0062 0069 006C 0065 0020 004E 0075 006D 0062 0065 0072 003A 0020 0039 0038 0034 0030 0039 0031 0032 0031 0039 0033 "

OK
```

its a hex value of 
Pls confirm Recharge of Rs. 10 to Mobile Number: 9840xxxxxx

how to confirm it using AT Command.
Modem Model : SIMCOM_SIM5215E

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code was correct. i forgot to attach the antenna with my modem.